# SET dotenv env in package.json not work Linux ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, express, package.json, nodemon, dotenv

This is my Setting in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server.js",
    "dev": "set NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT& nodemon backend/server",
    "prod": "set NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION& nodemon backend/server"
  },
```

This is my server.js looks like

```
const app = require('./app')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

//dotenv path
dotenv.config({ path: 'backend/config/config.env' })

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(
    `Server started on PORT: ${process.env.PORT}. in ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
  )
})
```

My config.env looks like

```
PORT = 4000
NODE_ENV = DEVELOPMENT
```

I Use nodemon,... and i set `node_env` variable like in `package.json`
so, when i called
`npm run dev` : `development`
`npm run prod` : `production`

but when i run `npm run prod`. i still got `server started on PORT 4000 in Development`.
Is there any error in my code ?

Comment: Maybe try: `"dev": "NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT nodemon backend/server",` (and similar for production). I believe there's no need for the `set` or the `&`

Comment: @msbit you're right i just removed set. its run. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the SET command as well as the & If on Linux:

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT nodemon backend/server",
"prod": "NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION nodemon backend/server"
```